# What is the Adobe Flex Framework for Mobile devices?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

currently worrking on Adobe Flex Technologies. I want to know whether Adobe had launched a Flex  platform for mobile devices or not. If Launched what is the name of the Framework  and please come with a sample example URL .

Answer (score 2):

[An early mobile branch of the Flex framework is expected to be available in 2010.](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/mobile/)

Answer (score 1):

HI,

Adobe officially declare Adobe Air platform for Android and name it "Burrito".
In previous version developer make application for Android using AIR 2.5 and make build (.apk) file for Android with cmd. Now in Flex Burrito (SDK) make entirely sole application for Android and Black Barry (Note Book).

for more information about the SDk and sample application visit the following links.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/blackberry_tablet_os_sdk.html
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flexsdk_hero/samples/
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile_development_hero_burrito.html

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ELIPS Studio, this cross platform environment allows you to develop native mobile apps for iPhone, Android, Symbian, Windows Mobile, in FLEX.
It's available as a plugin for Flex Builder.

[ELIPS Studio](http://developer.openplug.com/)

Answer (score 0):

in Flex using Air sdk 2.5 you create apps for android base mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

With Flex 4.6 development of mobile applications in Iphone, Android and even Blackberry is supported.